# multidimensional array values matched with another index array values then remove values from multidimensional in PHP 7

Tags: php, php-7

I am having below two arrays

```
    $firstArray = Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [MemberList] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 100
                    [1] => 5d6
                    [2] => 5d7
                )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [MemberList] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5d8
                    [1] => 200
                )
        )
)


$secondArray = Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 200
)
```

my question is if suppose `$secondArray` array values matched with `$firstArray` array then i have to remove the values from `$firstArray`

> my expected output

```
$firstArray = Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [MemberList] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5d6
                    [1] => 5d7
                )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [MemberList] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5d8
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: "_my question is ..._" is not a question though. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide your code in your question

Comment: Always post what you have done and where you are stuck. Stackoverflow is not a place to work for free to provide you a solution, it is only here to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newArray = array_map(
    function ($v) use ($secondArray) { 
        return ['MemberList' => array_diff($v['MemberList'], $secondArray)]; 
    }, 
    $firstArray
);
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/Rtqq2).